# A different method to render PHP code from an external file

Tags: php, html

I have a document (doc1) which is a HTML/PHP website with a "key" that acts as a place holder to replace the text.

I have a second document (doc2) that I want to display doc1 with an additional few lines of code.

Here is doc2 code currently:

```
    <?php

    $file = "doc1.php";
    $key = "<!-- Placeholder -->";
    $appcode = '!-- Replaced text -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newcode.css">
    <script src="newcode.js"></script>
    <script>
    newCode();
    </script';

    $index = fopen($file, "r") or die("Unable to open doc1.php");
    $code= fread($index,filesize("doc1.php"));
    fclose($index);

    $index_replaced = (preg_replace ($key, $appcode, $code));

    echo($index_replaced);

    ?>
```

So this works fine if I am dealing with a basic HTML file but if I use this method for a PHP file, the code doesn't render. How can I change this to make the doc1 code render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really missing the point of PHP entirely if you're doing this in your code, because PHP was primarily created as a templating language. It intends to solve the very problem you're trying to solve now, but in an elegant and fluid manner. Unlike the rigid and overly engineered manner you're attempting now.

If you document is infact PHP code then simply replace you `<!-- Placeholder -->` with `<?=$placeholder?>` and you can now do the following in your doc2 script to render it properly...

```php
    <?php

    $placeholder = <<<'EOT'
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newcode.css">
    <script src="newcode.js"></script>
    <script>
    newCode();
    </script'
EOT;

    include 'doc1.php';
```

And you're done!

---

To elaborate this works fine with both plain HTML or PHP files as long as they're being run through PHP. So say you had a document like `doc1.php` as below...

```php
<html>
    <?=$tag?>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello PHP!</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now in `doc2.php` you have...

```php
<?php
$tag = <<<'EOT'
<title>This is how templating is done</title>
EOT;

include 'doc1.php';
```

When you run `doc2.php` through PHP you get the final output as below...

```html
<html>
    <title>This is how templating is done</title>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello PHP!</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which based on your question is ***precisely*** what you're after :)

Answer (score -2):

In order to incorporate a PHP file and execute it, you need to use `include` or `require`. You can use the output buffer functions to capture the result.

```
ob_start();
require($file);
$code = ob_get_clean();
$index_replaced = preg_replace($key, $appcode, $code);
echo $index_replaced;
```